# Why do messages from one person go to iMessage on my Mac?

Tags: iphone, messages

I have an Android phone. Never owned an iPhone. For some reason, there is *one* single person who whenever he texts me the text goes to iMessage on my Mac laptop and does not go to my phone at all. His messages used to go to my phone, but they no longer do. When I text him from my phone, he receives it but when he replies to me it goes to my Mac and not my phone.

What could be causing this to happen and how can I make his texts go to my phone?

Comment: Android phones can't receive iMessages.

Comment: He may be strictly using iMessage on a Mac without a phone number, which means you'll likely not get it on your phone. In order for you to get "iMessages" on an android phone (excepting companies that claim that have a way to do so) is for him to send an SMS message to your phone number on your android phone. Is he doing that?

Comment: iMessage is able to send/receive messages to email addresses, rather than using SMS. That's presumably how he's sending to you. There's no way to redirect that to an Android phone.

Comment: You should ask your friend to fix how he's sending to you. The iPhone allows him to choose between the email and phone number, and he should select the phone.

Answer (score 0):

Your contact you confirm whether they're messaging your phone number or email.

In Messages, compose a new conversation and type in the name (yours). It will show the contact name and a contact method. It will be blue (iMessage) or green (SMS). If it's blue, tap the (>) icon on the right of the name and check the list of options. There should be a green phone number option on the list that should be selected.

Now that it's been corrected to the green phone number instead of the blue email, they should be able to message you and it should go to your android phone.

The phone number should be green in the list. If it isn't, then you might have to de-register your phone number: https://selfsolve.apple.com/deregister-imessage

Comment: That is so incredibly odd... but AFAICS you've not actually answered the question... i.e. assuming your theory of *"green v. blue"* is accurate - **how** did that number get registered/recognized as "blue"?

Comment: @Seamus I don’t think the number is blue, my answer is that the email is blue and that’s what the sender selected. I added that final note because it’s the only other explanation however unlikely.